# Setting up a Jenkins Pipeline build with parameters

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've been reading a lot about Jenkins 2.x and the pipeline system in order to create a setup with the following features;

1. A SCM managed Jenkinsfile.
2. Building each commit to the (git) repository.
3. Passing parameters through the webhook trigger.

So far I failed to build a working set-up because of various reasons, some of the things I tried are;

#### Multibranch Pipeline Setup

- My jenkinsfile from the git repository was picked up perfectly.
- Triggering through the git plugins `notifyCommit` webhook works well (http://localhost:8080/git/notifyCommit?url=...)
- There is no way to pass additional parameters this way.

So I was wondering if there is any other way to trigger these builds? The *trigger build remotely* and *[generic webhook](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin)* options do not show up when configuring the multibranch pipeline.

#### Regular Pipeline

- Creating the pipeline works and the trigger options mentioned earlier are available.
- Picked 'Jenkinsfile from SCM' and used git.
- Tried blank for 'branches', tried refs/heads/**,... a whole bunch of combinations.

Does Jenkins in this case assume a Jenkinsfile to be present in each branch? It seems like the `notifyCommit` webhook doesn't even trigger this.

If I force a manual build Jenkins doesn't know what to build it seems:

```
git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Seen branch in repository origin/a
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
   git tag -l # timeout=10
   git rev-parse refs/tags/tagY^{commit} # timeout=10
   git rev-parse refs/tags/tagX^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```