# How to avoid Jenkins triggering on git commands within Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins triggers whenever I push onto my remote branch. A pipeline is then run using my Jenkinsfile script.

Within the jenkinsfile I git push tags, this command however triggers Jenkins again and kicks off another build, which then in turn runs git push tags causing an infinite loop.

How can I avoid jenkins triggering on git commands within jenkinsfile?
I have spent over a week searching for a solution and nothing seems to be working, thank you.

Comment: Which trigger plugin are you using?

Comment: He's using [tag:jenkins-pipeline].

Comment: I am using jenkins-pipeline with the git plugin. Whenever a push event or merge event to a remote branch occurs jenkins is triggered

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using a *Multibranch Pipeline* or *GitHub/Bitbucket Organisation*.

You can *Suppress automatic SCM triggering* for all or specified branches under the *Branch Sources* configuration.

[image]

Comment: I am using pipeline not multibranch pipeline, therefore I do not have the option to suppress automatic SCM triggering

Comment: Any reason why you're using that? I really don't see an advantage of the Pipeline job type.

Comment: Its the way my company has their current jenkins configuration set up. I have been trying to find a solution on how to stop jenkins from triggering on my tag push command from the jenkinsfile for over a week. But no luck so far.

Comment: I decided to create a multibranch pipeline project, however How can I save configurations for a specific branch?

Comment: Use an `if` condition in your `Jenkinsfile`. You find the branch name in `env.BRANCH_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Jenkins triggers a build with [a (non-Jenkinsfile) refspec like `refs/tags/*`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29743054/6309)

So to avoid this, you could specify `refs/heads/*` (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44516870/6309)), or [check issue 507](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/507#issuecomment-299481993) and uncheck "lightweight checkout" to avoid getting tags.

Comment: But that's completely unrelated to [tag:jenkins-pipeline] (the technique behind `Jenkinsfile`s).

Comment: I already have the lightweight checkout box unchecked. As for the refs/heads/* would I place that path in the branch specifier box or the refspec box of the job configuration?

Comment: @Nadim branch specifier box (if not, test the other as well)

Comment: The trigger still happens when using  refs/heads/* Do you know another method that will allow Jenkins to trigger on all pushes except tag pushes?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin).

There are many alternativs like:

- Not trigger if commit message has a special format.
- Not trigger if a specific user pushes commits. Like a special user used in Jenkins.

From one of the test cases:

```
Scenario: Trigger a job when commit is pushed and the pusher is not named "build".

Given the following generic variables are configured:
  | variable   | expression    | expressionType  | defaultValue | regexpFilter  |
  | user       | $.pusher.name | JSONPath        |              |               |

Given filter is configured with:
  | text   | expression   |
  | $user  | ^((?!build)) |

Given received post content is:
"""
{
  "pusher": {
    "name": "baxterthehacker",
  }
}
"""
Then the job is triggered

Given received post content is:
"""
{
  "pusher": {
    "name": "build",
  }
}
"""
Then the job is not triggered
```